# Missing argument in nested functions (decorator)

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator

I have a following decorator:

```
from decorator import decorator
def my_decorator(key=None, timeout=None, retry=0):
    """
    My decorator
    """
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

    def _my_decorator(func):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        key = key or func.__name__

        @decorator
        def __my_decorator(f, *args, **kwargs):
            result = "abc"
            return result
        return __my_decorator(func)
    return _my_decorator
```

In first pdb section, the result of `locals()` is:

```
>>> locals()
{'key': None, 'retry': 0, 'pdb': <module 'pdb' from '/opt/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/pdb.pyc'>, 'timeout': None}
```

In second pdb section, the result of `locals()` is:

```
>>> locals()
{'timeout': None, 'retry': 0, 'pdb': <module 'pdb' from '/opt/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/pdb.pyc'>, 'func': <function get_items at 0x9e172cc>}
```

Exception without pdb:

```
key = key or func.__name__
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'key' referenced before assignment
```

Do You have any idea why `key` argument is gone in nested function _my_decorator? It's weird even more, because `timeout` and `retry` arguments are still accessible (despite the fact that this is normal behaviour in nested functions).

There is a workaround:

```
def my_decorator(key=None, timeout=None, retry=0):
    """
    My decorator
    """
    key2 = key

    def _my_decorator(func):
        key = key2 or func.__name__
    ...
```

but it's not a solution (argument `key` is still gone in `_my_decorator`, but `key2` is now accessible)

Python version: 2.7.3

Comment: How are you using `key` in the decorator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you bind a variable name in an inner scope, it will be omitted from the closure on the outer scope.  This is because otherwise subsequent code would not know which binding to reference:

```
def outer(x=None):
    def inner(y=0):
        if y:
            x = y
        return x    # outer.x or inner.x?
```

The fix is to rename your variables so they don't shadow enclosing scopes:

```
def my_decorator(key=None, timeout=None, retry=0):
    def _my_decorator(func):
        func_key = key or func.__name__
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning *to* `key`, which makes that variable a local. You cannot do what you are trying to achieve here with Python 2 (in Python 3 you can mark it as `nonlocal`).

The work-around is to make `key` a mutable, then mutate it's contents instead of assigning to it:

```
from decorator import decorator
def my_decorator(key=None, timeout=None, retry=0):
    """
    My decorator
    """
    key = [key]

    def _my_decorator(func):
        key[0] = key[0] or func.__name__
```

Now we are *mutating* `key`, not assigning to the variable. To put it another way, we are executing the moral equivalent of `key.__setitem__(0, key[0] or func.__name__)`, wheras your code was executing `locals()['key'] = key or func.__name`, an act that marks `key` as a local variable.